# CustomVision API returns “Operation returned an invalid status code: 'Bad Request'”

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I get this error when using the CustomVisionPredictionClient like so:

```
var predictionApi = new CustomVisionPredictionClient()
{
    ApiKey = _predictionKey,
    Endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
};
var result = await predictionApi.ClassifyImageAsync(project.Id, _modelName, imageData);
```

- The project/project id is retrieved via the training API, on which I can call GetProjects() without a problem. It should be correct, if I change it to something wrong I get a "not found" exception.
- _modelName is the published name of the iteration ("xxxRecognition", see screenshot below), it should also be correct, when I change it I get "not found".
- imageData is just a FileStream from a PNG image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I created an "Object Detection" type project and tried to use it with ClassifyImage() which has to be used with "Classification" type projects. So I have to use DetectImage() instead. :)

Answer (score -1):

There's two items to address here.

### Your particular "Bad Request"

Your example, specifically, has one or more of these problems that you haven't really included.

1. The `_modelName` is malformed
2. The `imageData` is not formatted properly
3. Some configuration, likely of request headers, is missing or incorrect

That's about the most we can provide from the example you've given.  But here's the *other* concern that will benefit you greatly in the future: "Bad Request" tells you a *lot* about what's happened.

### More about "Bad Request" in general

If you look at ranges within [HTTP status codes](https://httpstatusdogs.com/) you'll notice a pattern in the "error" ranges.

1. In `4xx` the requester (you) did something wrong and you can correct it.
2. In `5xx` the responder did something wrong and you *cannot* correct it.

Beneath that:

1. In `404 Not Found` it seems the request was formed well but the responder cannot find what you've asked for
2. In `401 Unauthorized` you didn't provide any kind of identity
3. In `403 Forbidden` you *did* provide an identity but you're not allowed to perform this action

But in `400 Bad Request` the responder couldn't validate your request as good input *at all*.  That means you can look at the API documentation again, compare it with your implementation, and try again.